# Springfox Swagger vs Swagger maven plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

There are [Springfox](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) implementation of the Swagger 2 specification and [Swagger Maven Plugin](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin). What's the difference between them? When should I prefer one over another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagger maven plugin generates the swagger specification from Java annotations.

Springfox generates a whole web-based UI from Java annotations, with documentation, samples and functionality to try the operations out.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious difference I see is that SpringFox doesn't require you to manually swagger-annotate classes as swagger-maven-plugin does.

The second one is the swagger spec generation time:
compilation time vs build phase, respectively.

**SpringFox**
Without any handwritten documentation, it can generate a lot of information about your API just by inspecting classes in your application.

[Swagger and SpringFox](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/documenting-spring-boot-rest-api-swagger-springfox/)

**Swagger-maven-plugin**
Enables your Swagger-annotated project to generate Swagger artifacts during the maven build phase. It generates the spec as a build artifact to be used in downstream Swagger tooling.

[Swagger-Maven-Plugin](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin)